# Unable to connect to the remote SMTP server

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmailId", "Password");
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("gmailId", "Testing Mail");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("someMailId"));
mail.Body = "This is a test email. Please ignore or delete.";
mail.Subject = "Mail Testing";
smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

I am trying to use the code above to send mail. It was working fine for me, but when I tried to use it in another system it gave me an error ("Unable to connect to the remote server").

Comment: Which error? Please specify

Comment: Well what can you tell us about the differences between the systems? My guess is that in the one that doesn't work, you need to set a proxy somewhere - but we can't really tell. Additionally, please read the Markdown help for information about how to format blocks of code.

Comment: If your `other system` is in a corporate network or alike, then your outgoing requests to port 587 would be blocked by firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I think your gmail account is secured with mobile sms facility. If you access your gmail account from other macine than a sms will recieve from gmail for varification.
Please off this functionality and try again.

Comment: Hi Maruti.Thanks for your reply but my gmail account is not secured with mobile sms..

Comment: I had similar problem because of this connection to the gmail server was not established. Try to mail from other gmail account.